# Can I add a button in an Access stock program to search Outlook?

Tags: ms-access, outlook, outlook-2007, ms-access-2010

Is there a way I can make a button on an access database that automatically searches Outlook? My idea is to have a button besides the email address which can be clicked and it will open Outlook, or jump to Outlook if its open, and search all items for the customer's email address?

Comment: If it can be done, it will be very slow, I suspect, as the Outlook message store is not indexed. Most operations like this are very slow in Outlook because of that fact. Basically, it's easy to send stuff to Outlook (emails, tasks, etc.), but much less efficient to retrieve things from it.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a VBA sub that takes a search string and searches in either the existing instance of Outlook or creates a new instance to search.  Tested in Office 2010.  It's worth putting in a real error handler if this is going to be used by others.

You'll need to make a reference to "Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library" or whatever version you have.  You can do this in the VBA window via Tools->References.

If you're feeling fancy you can display the search results in Access itself with the help of the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220071%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method.

```
Sub outlookSearch(searchString As String)
Dim app As Outlook.Application

'This will throw an error if there's no instances of Outlook running
'   so resume after the error.
On Error Resume Next
Set app = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0 'Replace this with a real error handler

'If the app variable is empty
If app Is Nothing Then
    'Create a new instanc eof outlook
    Set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Add an explorer showing the inbox
    app.Explorers.Add app.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Make the explorer visible
    app.Explorers(1).Activate
End If

'Search all folders for searchString
app.ActiveExplorer.search searchString, olSearchScopeAllFolders

Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. I've been so busy I never got a chance to follow this up any more. Thank you very much for your input @Banjoe I will try this and come back and let you know how I get on. Thank you :) :)

Comment: Still not had a chance to do this! I will vote as soon as I do it! Thank you again, sorry for the delay.